# Mordern CMake for Gazebo

Tags: cmake

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone!

I was wondering if the "modern" cmake implementation for configuration file was implemented somewhere on gazebo?

By modern cmake I'm talking of [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-relocatable-packages). So to use add_library(gazebo STATIC IMPORTED) instead of the traditional GAZEBO_LIBRARIES cmake varibales. It would just required to install the EXPORT target in the CMakeLists and to include the output files into the gazebo-config.cmake

I saw that ignition-math2 has this mechanism.

If it doesn't exist, would it be interesting to do it ?

All the best :D

XB32Z

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13828/mordern-cmake-for-gazebo/) by [XB32Z](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2505/xb32z/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The bets place to see current non-released developments of Gazebo would be the `defualt`branch of the repository. I don't think that we currently have a relocatable cmake module in Gazebo. It would be a fantastic contribution.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2016-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2